# CSS3 Selectors for achievements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of each `.achievement` div. The content is being generated dynamically so I can't add a class easily to each one.

I have it working with selectors like `.achievements .grid-row:nth-child(odd) .col-1-2:nth-child(even) .achievement` but they seem a little bloated. The problem I'm having is that the `.achievement` div is nested a few deep so I can't just use an `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` on it.

I'm just checking to see if there is a better way to select those that I'm missing out on.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/gxLqV/)

**HTML**

```html
<div class="achievements">

    <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="achievement">
                <p>Testing...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="achievement">
                <p>Testing...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="achievement">
                <p>Testing...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="achievement">
                <p>Testing...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.achievements .grid-row:nth-child(odd) .col-1-2:nth-child(even) .achievement {
    background: #5891bc;
}

.achievements .grid-row:nth-child(even) .col-1-2:nth-child(odd) .achievement {
    background: #96c3e6;
    color: #585858;
}

.achievements .grid-row:nth-child(even) .col-1-2:nth-child(even) .achievement {
    background: #d3dfe7;
    color: #585858;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably take out the class selectors (`.grid-row` and `.col-1-2`) because `nth-child` [doesn't respond to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class) (i.e. they're not doing anything):

```
.achievements :nth-child(even) :nth-child(odd) .achievement
```

In the future, CSS3's `toggle()` function (which cycles through values) could simplify things:

```
.achievement {
  background: toggle(#ccc, #5891bc, #96c3e6, #d3dfe7);
}
```

Sadly this [isn't supported by any browsers](http://css3clickchart.com/#toggle) yet. Also proposed is an [`:nth-match` selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#nth-match-pseudo), which would let you do:

```
:nth-of-type(n4+1 of .achievement) {
  background: #5891bc;
}
```

Comment: You can use a class with :nth-child selectors, it just needs to have a parent. http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/fZGvH/90/. Thanks for the links, wasn't aware of those ones yet, they look cool.

Comment: No problem! Hmm nope, that doesn't work for me on the latest Chrome (25). It sort of works on FF/Safari, but it breaks if there are any sibling elements (which sort of defeats the point of using the class selector in the first place).